# How to read, modify header and save .7 file with rest of its data?

Tags: python, ctypes

.7 file contains MRS data from GE scanner. I want to read its header, change some of its fields values like scan date, etc., and save a new .7 file with modified header and rest of the data should be same.

Code:

```
from ctypes import *
import ge_util as utilge

class PfileHeaderLittle(LittleEndianStructure):
    """
    Contains the ctypes Structure for a GE P-file rdb header.
    Dynamically allocate the ctypes _fields_ list later depending on revision
    """
    _pack_   = 1
    _fields_ = utilge.get_pfile_hdr_fields(20.0)

hdr = PfileHeaderLittle()

fname = r"P16896.7"
filelike = open(fname, 'rb')
filelike.seek(0)
filelike.readinto(hdr)

print("hdr: ", hdr)
print("hdr: ", type(hdr.rhe_patname))
print("hdr: ", hdr.rhe_patname)
hdr.rhe_patname = b"CHANGE_IT"
print("hdr: ", hdr.rhe_patname)

with open("my_file.7", 'wb') as file:
    file.write(hdr)
```

Output:

```
hdr:  <__main__.PfileHeaderLittle object at 0x0000025F75D09F48>
hdr:  <class 'bytes'>
hdr:  b'MRS TEST1'
hdr:  b'CHANGE_IT'
```

This code reads the header, modify one field and save it back. But, rest of the data is not saved. I read the saved file again and confirmed that the header is modified, but rest of the data is not present in the new file. **How can I save modified header and save a new file with rest of the data?**

Here is `ge_util`: https://scion.duhs.duke.edu/vespa/project/export/3828/trunk/common/ge_util.py 
`P16896.7` file: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1zqQbOUwlIa1_rv9OAVA0sQfEEaOFsne0

Comment: You only write back the header (`file.write(hdr)`).

Comment: So, how can I save `hdr` as well as rest of the data?

Comment: You have to read it (it starts after the header) in the original file, and write it to the target file (after the header, of course).

Comment: Okay, so how of find the point to read? And once I found it how to append it with new header and save it?

Comment: You'll have to check the *ge\_util* doc how to get the header size in bytes. Then, a *Google* search will yield tons of results for reading / writing files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you have modified `hdr`, find its byte length by `len(bytes(hdr))`. Use `seek` to get to that location and `read()` rest of the file. Now, concatenate that with the new header, and save a new file:

```
filelike.seek(len(bytes(hdr)))
b = filelike.read()

c = bytes(hdr)+b

file = open('New_File.7', 'wb')
file.write(c)
file.close()
```